# React with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, pwa, react

I have to use **ReactJS as a frontend for Magento 2**. Below is one of the github repo I looked after to integrate but it seems it's **not that efficient**, even not working in my case.

[Check GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Genaker/reactmagento2)

I've also looked at **PWA for Magento 2** but not sure how it will work.

What I was actually thinking of as a solution is that something like having a separate **frontend developed in ReactJS** and **data could be fetched using Magento 2's REST APIs**. Similar approach I've used in a recent **BigCommerce** project and it's working as per expectation however further performance testing is in progress.

Kindly suggest if using the above mentioned approach for Magento 2, is a good idea considering all the below factors:

- Version Upgrade
- Scalability
- Performance
- Security
- Resource Utilization
- Re-usability

**If you have any different thoughts, please feel free to discuss.**

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can take a look at [GraphCommerce](https://www.graphcommerce.org/). A Reactjs storefront for Magento 2 and Adobe Commerce. It's built with Reactjs, Nextjs, Typescript, Mui and it is open source.

It seems to meet all your requirements:

- Version Upgrade: Uses Magento 2.4.3 GraphQL API
- Scalability: Next.js for SSG and SSR
- Performance: includes Image optimization, JS bundling, CDN caching
- Security: Uses the native GraphQL API
- Resource Utilization: Caching at CDN level (pages and images)
- Re-usability: Uses Mui UI library, so you can just style components

Comment: Thank you @Erwin Otten

Answer (score 1):

The [pwa-studio](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio) project is doing exactly what you are looking to do, only it's using graphQL where possible (m2 is still working on full graphQL support, so where there are gaps the pwa-studio project is using REST). The project is still ongoing, so if you were to start using it today for a project that is shipping in 2-3 months, you will find some heavy core code changes from here to there and some feature gaps that might or might not be closed. So i would highly suggest that if you have a very tight timeline to be very careful with pwa-studio. One good place to follow the project is the Magento slack channel `https://magentocommeng.slack.com/`. You can join by sending an email to `engcom@magento.com`.

But in your case, this would act as a perfect spring board for understanding how to implement React into m2. Since a huge portion of features have been implemented, you can take parts that you need and customize from there. If you were considering building an integration from scratch, pwa-studio could be a great learning tool as you build.

A project that i have not used but is production ready is [ScandiPWA](https://scandipwa.com/). I have talked to a few people on that team and they are all really knowledgeable and have a really nice project.

Another project that might be of interest is [Vue Storefront](https://www.vuestorefront.io/). It's not React, but is production ready and could be a great way to get your project realized.

Comment: Thanks @circlesix .  I'll look at the solution, you've given. However, there is no such specific timeline from a client. Instead, I was planning to use this new tech stack for future developments. But, I think I should wait a bit more to actually start integrating PWA studio. Till then, learning and exploring PWA studio shall be the great idea, I believe.  

I'm not marking your answer as accepted for now because I need to explore the things as suggested by you. But, it was really helpful. Thanks buddy!

Comment: Yeah, i don't think there is one answer to "accept", better to keep getting ideas on this question and see what other people have to say. One good resource is to join the Magento community slack channel `https://magentocommeng.slack.com/`. There are a bunch of people talking PWA as the project evolves. I'm going to add that to my answer.